# External Fonts not visible in Chrome until repaint

Tags: google-chrome, font-face, repaint

Using Chrome I am experiencing an issue with a local site where when the site initially loads, none of the fonts are visible.  If I then hit F12 or resize the screen then the fonts all become visible.

The fonts are being loaded from Google Fonts using font-face, I am assuming that resizing the screen causes a repaint which is fixing the issue.

I have found a similar issue listed with Chromium at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by including the javascript part of the font from google fonts..

It was annoying the heck out of me, so I did some experiementing and adding the javascript font insert instead of the css worked like a charm.. =D

From

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Orbitron::latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>
```

Both found on the google fonts page fixed it LIKE A BOSS for me at least.. ;)